# Complex sentence using "so that"

Tags: grammar

Could you help me, please? Which of the two sentences is correct?

> Could you phone them so that he may explain it?

or

> Could you phone them so that he might explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are technically correct. However, "may" works better, since "might" makes it sound like there is a probability that he will not explain it.

> Some people insist that you should use may (present tense) when talking about a >current situation and might (past tense) when talking about an event that >happened in the past. For example:
>
> *I may go home early if I’m tired.* (present tense)
>
> *He might have visited Italy before settling in Nuremberg.* (past tense)
>
> But there is a distinction between may have and might have in certain contexts. If the truth of a situation is still not known at the time of speaking or writing, either of the two is acceptable:
>
> *By the time you read this, he may have made his decision.*
>
> *I think that comment might have offended some people.*
>
> If the event or situation referred to did not in fact occur, it's better to use might have:
>
> *The draw against Italy might have been a turning point, but it didn't turn out like that*.

Source:[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/may-or-might)

Comment: What makes you think "may" doesn't make it sound like there is a probability that he will not explain it?

Comment: may is more commonly used than might in my experience, and might is more often used when talking about probability.

Comment: You need to include your reference/research in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. English is my second language, so it's sometimes very difficult to understand some nuances.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are good , the difference is that may implies a stronger possibility that the action will take place than might .